# google chrome extension perform action on loading pages doesnt work with google and facebook

Tags: facebook, google-chrome-extension, onload

I am developing a chrome extention that do some action on page load for example alert welcome 
I am using Jquery to dect the document.ready  **it works perfect with all sites but facebook and google I need it works with FB** 
here is the manifest.json file

```
    {
  "name": "Me",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "ME",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
     "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://api.flickr.com/"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
       "js": ["jquery.js", "popup.js"]



    }
  ]
}
```

and here is pop.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("Welcome");
    alert("Welcome");
});
```

and even I don't use Jquery and used the JS method directly still doesnt work

```
  alert("Welcome");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have HTTPS enabled on Facebook and Google, your content scripts will run on HTTP sites only.
Change your "matches" field value to "<all_urls>" to include HTTPS sites.